# how can I pass arguments to the query method in apollo?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client, redux-thunk

I am using apollo client to fetch the data.
And I want it to only get those todos that are made by the logged in user only.

But this piece doesn't work

Source code:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const todoService = {
getTodoItems: () => gql`
    query todoQuery($loggedUserId: String!) {
      todo(where: { userId: { _eq: $loggedUserId } }, order_by: { createdAt: desc }) {
        id
        todo {
            title,
            body,
            status
        }
        userId
      }
    }
}
`
```

**Redux thunk file**

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { apolloClient } from '@/Apollo';
import { todoService } from './_graphql';

export const todoThunk = {
getTodoItems: createAsyncThunk(`db/getTodoItems`, async (loggedUserId: string) => {
    const response = await apolloClient.query({
      query: todoService.getTodoItems(),
      variables: { loggedUserId },
      fetchPolicy: `network-only`,
    });
    return response;
  }),
```

**React Component**

```
  useEffect(
     dispatch(todoThunk.getTodoItems(loggedUserId));
  ,[dispatch])
```

However it works when I hard code the userId in place of variable `loggedUserId` like this:

```
export const todoService = {
getTodoItems: () => gql`
    query todoQuery {
      todo(where: { userId: { _eq: "some_hard_coded_id" } }, order_by: { createdAt: desc }) {
        id
        todo {
            title,
            body,
            status
        }
        userId
      }
    }
}
`
```

Comment: `todo(where: { userId: { _eq: $loggedUserId `..... test query in the playground (using variables) before coding

Comment: tested using variables? show it

Comment: I tested it in hasura api but not with variables
I runned this query there and it worked
todo(where: { userId: { _eq: 'id_here' }}

Comment: again, test using variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me.

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const todoService = {
getTodoItems: () => gql`
    query todoQuery($loggedUserId: uuid! = loggedUserId) {
      todo(where: { userId: { _eq: $loggedUserId } }, order_by: { createdAt: desc }) {
        id
        todo {
            title,
            body,
            status
        }
        userId
      }
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed a `$` sign

try:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const todoService = {
getTodoItems: () => gql`
    query todoQuery($loggedUserId: String!) {
      todo(where: { userId: { _eq: $loggedUserId } }, order_by: { createdAt: desc }) {
        id
        todo {
            title,
            body,
            status
        }
        userId
      }
    }
}
`
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo. it didn't works with after adding $ sign either